# Unexpected DIV border lines on ipad

Tags: html, css, ipad

as you can see on the picture below, there's some kind of black border line when I look at my website on an iPad. Would you know why and how to get read of that?
Many thanks,
[image]

```
.banner2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #2165CB;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.banner3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 80px;
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background: #2690CD;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to just use: `.banner2 img, .banner3 img{ border: 0; }`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but unfortunately that did not work

Comment: No problem, would you be able to post the HTML?

Comment: Sure. Here it is: http://goo.gl/AXYpll (look at the bottom of the screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that they're images so you can just use:

```
.banner2 img, .banner3 img{
    border: 0;
}
```

If they're not images then just add `border: 0;` to the CSS styles for both `.banner2` and `.banner3`.